# images won't display and css doesnt work in GitHub pages

Tags: html, css, image, github, github-pages

I created a portfolio using github pages but the images and the css in the site won't load.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

```
<img src="../avatar/avatarmakercolor.png" class="avatar">
```

This how folders are organised

```
docs
       index.html
avatar
        avatarmakercolor.png
css
        style.css
```

[image]

I have tried to change PNG to png and remove all the capital letters from my files but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong path.
Change the link tag to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

And the image tag to this:

```
<img src="../images/image.png" class="avatar">
```

*This is based on the info you provided about the folder structure. Change as needed*

Comment: No my path isn't wrong I just made mistake when I made this post, I've just corrected it and the css and images work fine when I'm on my computer it's only on github pages that it won't work.

Comment: Ok then if you can post the tags as you've used and and your directory structure in github pages, it would be helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/AswanJM/aswanjm.github.io

Comment: From what it seems right now is probably you 've not configured the docs folder to be the branch serving github pages. See https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch